# Android in-app-billing queryInventoryAsync returns sku and purchase item size 0

Tags: android, payment, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I'm calling queryInventoryAsync in my code. Response is OK but the list of skuMap and purchaseMap returned to me in the inventory list is empty. My products are active in the developer console.

The result is succeded but the Inventory inv return 0 items, so I cannot get pennding purchase to continue consuming that purchase.

I have been facing this mistake since 2 days. It was working fine before.

This my debug output.

[image]

How else can I get this item's data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because your app is not published on Play Store. To test anything in In-App Billing you need to publish the app on Play Store in Alpha/Beta/Production channel.